# Create column based on datecolumn values in R

Tags: r, datetime

I wrote a function that creates column based on a datetime column using parameters  starting and ending dates, but I can't get it to work.

`df` is a data frame object.

```
create_gv <- function(df, s_ymd, e_ymd, char) {
    df<-get(df)
    for (i in (1:nrow(df))) {
        ymd <- format(df[i,1],"%y%m%d")
        if ((strptime(ymd,format = "%y%m%d") >= strptime(s_ymd,format = "%y%m%d") & strptime(ymd,format = "%y%m%d") <= strptime(e_ymd,format = "%y%m%d")) == TRUE) {
            df$group_var[i]<-char
    }
  }
}


create_gv("example","171224","171224","D")
```

I get

```
> example
           start_time group_var
1 2017-12-24 10:42:39        NA
2 2017-12-24 10:44:31        NA
3 2018-01-14 12:05:53        NA
4 2018-01-14 12:22:12        NA
```

Reproducible data frame named `example` here:

```
example <- structure(list(start_time = structure(c(1514112159, 1514112271, 1515931553, 1515932532), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),  group_var = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("start_time", "group_var"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Desired output:

```
           start_time group_var
1 2017-12-24 10:42:39         D
2 2017-12-24 10:44:31         D
3 2018-01-14 12:05:53         NA
4 2018-01-14 12:22:12         NA
```

Comment: (1) `== TRUE` is redundant, you just don't need it; (2) why `format` (date/timestamp to string) then `strptime` (string to timestamp)? **Most important**: (3) if you check inside your function (`debug(create_gv)` and step through it), you'll see that `e_ymd-s_ymd` returns `Time difference of 0 secs`. If you instead use `"171225"` for the `e_ymd`, you'll get a day's range and closer to what you want.

Comment: @r2evans I did ```strptime``` back again because I wanted to compare the ```y-m-d```. I see your point, but I still don't get why ```171224``` wouldn't work? The comparison I wrote is greater or equal and less or equal.

Comment: @r2evans My bad, I simply forgot return(df)!!

Comment: The comparison you wrote is *not* the same. Realize that your `"171224"` (for both `s_ymd` and `e_ymd`) is converted to a full `POSIXct` of `"2017-12-24 00:00:00.000000 PST"` (or whatever tz you have). This is typically *displayed* on your console as `"2017-12-24 PST"`, but that's a cosmetic thing. When you see the midnight (all zeroes time), perhaps you realize why (1) none of your `start_time` occur before `e_ymd`, and in fact why (2) nothing can be between a midnight and itself.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, my understanding is that you want to check if the date in a row  is between the start and end date (which are scalars), and update the value of `group_var` accordingly.

The `lubridate` package provides a set of tools which allow to easily work with dates. In order to compare dates you don't need to format them. `format` only helps with the viewing of these dates. I have used the `dplyr` package which allows you to easily perform data transformations.

To solve the problem, we use the `dplyr::mutate` function which transforms a column by row, as a function of other columns. In this case, the date column in our dataset (`start_time`) is to compared with scalar start and end times in order to codify the `group_var` variable.

```
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

char <- "D"
# Randomly setting the start and end times for the purpose of the example. Any value can be passed to this.
s_ymd <- df$start_time[1] - 5000
e_ymd <- df$start_time[2] + 5000

df %>% dplyr::mutate(group_var = ifelse(start_time > s_ymd & start_time < 
                                         e_ymd,
                                         char, NA)) -> df
df
```

To use a function directly, write:

```
create_gv <- function(start_time, s_ymd, e_ymd, char){
    g_var <- ifelse(start_time > s_ymd & start_time < e_ymd,
                                    char, NA)
    return(g_var)
}

df %>% dplyr::mutate(group_var = create_gv(start_time, !!s_ymd, !!e_ymd, 
                                                                !!char))
```

Here since `s_ymd`, `e_ymd` and `char` are scalars (i.e. not columns in the data frame), we need to unquote them. Note that the `mutate` function works on vectorized functions as desired.